# Can F3H used as a mandatory prefix for instruction other than POCNT, LZCNT and ADOX instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

As it said in [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Combined Volumes 2A and 2B: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/)

> 2.1.1 Instruction Prefixes
>
> **F3H** is also used as a mandatory prefix for POPCNT, LZCNT and ADOX instruction.

But in

> 2.1.2 Opcodes
>
> For example, CVTDQ2PD consists of the following sequence: **F3** 0F E6. The first byte is a mandatory prefix (it is not considered as a repeat prefix).

Can I say that if the first byte of the opcode in the intel's-manual is F3H, it is a mandatory prefix for that instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In the sequence `0F E6`, the first byte `0F` is a two-byte-opcode escape.
The other byte `E6` is translated according to the table in Appendix A (Section A.3) and reported in short form here

[image: CVTDQ2PD and siblings]

The upper row is the low nibble of the byte, the first column is the higher one.

We can see that without the `F3` byte, the sequence `0F E6` doesn't encode any instruction.
`66 0F E6` encodes `vcvttpd2dq`
`F3 0F E6` encodes `vcvtdq2pd`
`F2 0F E6` encodes `vcvtpd2dq`

So yes, the `F3` is mandatory.

---

Admittedly what Intel did was a quirk, the byte `F3` is a real `rep` prefix but the CPU doesn't interpret that as such.
You can think of `0F E6` as an unnamed instruction, say `unm2`, such that:

- `unm2` behaves as `ud2`
- `rep unm2` behaves as `vcvtdq2pd`
- `repne unm2` behaves as `vcvtpd2dq`
- `unm2` with a size override behaves as `vcvttpd2dq`

Comment: Thanks for the detail explaination.